# Request' object has no attribute 'full_path after click on logout from website odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

After click on logout from website (frontend) get below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 242, in _handle_exception
    response = super(ir_http, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 158, in _handle_exception
    return request._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 788, in _handle_exception
    return super(HttpRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_http.py", line 183, in _dispatch
    result = request.dispatch()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 847, in dispatch
    r = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 323, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 316, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 966, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 516, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/website/controllers/main.py", line 44, in index
    return request.registry['ir.http'].reroute(first_menu.url)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 209, in reroute
    return self._dispatch()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 175, in _dispatch
    key = self.get_page_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/website/models/ir_http.py", line 94, in get_page_key
    return (self._name, "cache", request.uid, request.lang, request.httprequest.full_path)
AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'full_path'
```

Any solution how fix this problem?

Tnx for help!..............................................................

Comment: Where is code example? Error is already telling you what is the problem, you are trying to use `full_path` but object doesn't has it that's all

Comment: @Dachi Darchiashvili  I don't have code example, only when click on logout button get above error. Maybe is problem in my url, I use VPS eg. 123.123.123.123:8069/

Comment: its not url problem